# Тестирование WP без hyper-v

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

Стоит начальная версия win8.1, установить на нее hyper-v нельзя. Возникает вопрос, как можно тестировать приложения для WP без него?

Answer (score 2):

Если занимаетесь разработкой, то советую поставить полноценную ось. В принципе можно с помощью разных выкрутасов запустить образ и без Hyper-V, но количество проблем будет зашкаливающим, и вы сами не будете этому рады.

Также вы всегда можете запустить приложение на реальном устройстве.

Answer (score 1):

Тестировать приложения непосредственно на телефоне. Для этого нужно получить учетку разработчика и разлочить телефон

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, что эмулятор заведётся только на машине с поддержкой Hyper-V (для этого нужен мин Windows 8.1 pro и CPU с поддержкой Hyper-V).
Остаётся только один вариант, покупать реальный телефон и девелоперскую лицензию (просто телефона будет мало). В сети правда гуляют статьи, как разлочить телефон, без лицензии, но я не пробовал этого делать, так что не могу сказать, на сколько это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio поддерживает отладку и без Hyper-V. Как на компьютере, так и на конечном устройстве с использованием удаленной отладки.

Comment: без аккаунта разработчика?